# C++ typedef inheritance ambiguous problem

Tags: c++, typedef, ambiguous

I wish to use a helper class which would only make few Qt typedef aliases for the given template argument. Ofc ambiguous comes a cross very quickly and also quite often with my current design situation on the project, since one wish to access `Base` as well as `Derived`. Not sure if this problem is somehow workaround-able, still giving it a shot. Example:

```
template <class T> class SmartAlias
{
public:
    typedef QSharedPointer<T> Shared;
};

class Base : public SmartAlias<Base>
{
};

class Derived : public Base, public SmartAlias<Derived>
{
};

Base::Shared base;  // Normally works
Derived::Shared derived;  // ambiguous problem
```

Any ideas of a better solution? Thanks.

**SUMMARY/UPDATE/SOLUTION**

To sum it up, if one wishes to use this, go with Anton Savin idea, which can also be extended for multiple inheritance using virtual inheritance:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T, typename... MyBases> class SmartAlias :  virtual public MyBases... {
public:
    typedef std::vector<T> Shared;
};

class Base : public SmartAlias<Base>
{
};

class Derived : public SmartAlias<Derived, Base>
{
};

class MiniBase : public SmartAlias<MiniBase> {};

class MiniDerived : public SmartAlias<MiniDerived, MiniBase, Derived> { 
public: 
    MiniDerived() : MiniBase(), Derived() 
    {
    }
};

int main() {
    Base::Shared base;
    Derived::Shared derived; 
    MiniDerived::Shared md;
}
```

I on the other hand will stick with my current solution that Frerich Raabe mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly specify in `Derived` which of two `Shared`s you want to use:

```
class Derived : public Base, public SmartAlias<Derived>
{
public:
    using Shared = SmartAlias<Derived>::Shared;
    // or in pre-C++11
    typedef SmartAlias<Derived>::Shared Shared;
};
```

---

Here is another option which doesn't require to add typedefs to all classes. Instead it modifies the hierarchy inserting `SmartAlias` between `Base` and `Derived`:

```
template <typename T, typename MyBase = void> class SmartAlias : public MyBase
{
public:
    typedef typename SmartAlias<T>::Shared Shared;
};

template <typename T> class SmartAlias<T, void> 
{
public:
    typedef QSharedPointer<T> Shared;
};

class Base : public SmartAlias<Base>
{
};

class Derived : public SmartAlias<Derived, Base>
{
};
```

Comment: @krizajb in pre-C++11 you should use `typedef` instead

Comment: Looks good. Forgot to describe a more detailed requirements making this solution cover only the basics. What if `Derived` extends `Base` but also extends another class which is also extended on same principle as `Derived` and `Base`. I get a compiler error, will analyze and get back to you.

Comment: Example:
    class MiniBase : public SmartAlias<MiniBase>
    {
    };

    class MiniDerived :
        public SmartAlias<MiniDerived, MiniBase>,
        public SmartAlias<MiniDerived, Derived>
    {
    };

Everything works till I wish to call non default constructor of MiniBase or Derived in initialization list. Will look into it.

Comment: Think I will have to use virtual inheritance for that one to work, which isn't the best solution out there :/

Comment: @krizajb Virtual inheritance won't help you. This will never work in case of multiple inheritance - you have to define `Shared` inside the class itself like in my first example. Or you can move multiple inheritance to SmartAlias itself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64862/discussion-between-krizajb-and-anton-savin).

Answer (score 2):

Quite frankly, seeing code which uses (public) inheritance for code reuse instead of interface reuse always makes me nervous. And a class which has 'Smart' in its name is almost a code smell to me. How about just

```
class Base
{
public:
    typedef QSharedPointer<Base> Shared;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    typedef QSharedPointer<Derived> Shared;
};
```

Comment: This is my current design. Was only thinking of making it easier and tried making a reusable code. As you probably know, there are plenty of other smart pointers :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you create a Derived object it will intern create an object for Base that will intern create an object for SmartAlias and then you intensionally deriving SmartAlias from Derived. So you are having 2 SmartAlias objects for a single Derived object. When you want access a member of SmartAlias using Derived object surely it will lead to ambiguous. So you need not have SmartAlias as the immediate base for Derived.

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence. I am actually coming up with some crazy idea, giving it a shot :)

Comment: class Derived : public Base
{
};is enough.

Comment: It's not if i wish to use my code as exampled above.